# How to use html test runner to generate html report in pytest?

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I am able to generate HTML report in pytest using pytest.html but i wanted to know is there a way to generate HTML report of pytest using HTML test runner ?

Comment: `pytest` does not use `unittest`-style runners, so it is unfortunately not possible out of the box.

Comment: hmmm ok @hoefling and thank you for your response